# に vs で with ～っぱなし

Tags: grammar

Let us take two sentences

水を出しっぱなしにしないでください

窓をあけっぱなしでかけてしまった

Is that correct to conclude that ～っぱなし is as just as ～まま?

What is the difference in and logic behind using the particles に and で here?

Comment: `窓をあけっぱなしでかけてしまった` -> Isn't it 窓をあけっぱなし**で** でかけてしまった ?

Comment: The grammar behind this is not specific to ～っぱなし, because [`verb + っぱなし` as a whole simply works as a no-adjective](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/53713/5010). Try to understand this more generally; when to use に or で after a na/no-adjective? But I feel a person who might ask this type of question should be already familiar with how to use `adj + にする`, `adj + になる`, `adj + で + verb`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether to use 「に」 or 「で」 depends on the verb that follows.

> 1)「～～っぱなし + **に** + **する**」
>
> 2)「～～っぱなし + **で** + **other verbs**」

Thus, your two sentences follow the rules above.

> 1) 「水を出しっぱなし + **に** + **しない** + でください。」

「しない」 is the negative form of 「する」.

"***Please do not leave the water running***."

> 2) 「窓をあけっぱなし + **で** + **でかけて** + しまった。」

The verb following the 「で」 is 「でかける」.

"***I (accidentally) went out with my windows open***."

> Is that correct to conclude that ～っぱなし is as just as ～まま?

Yes.  Thus, you can also say:

1) 「水を出しっぱなしの**まま**にしないでください。」

2) 「窓を開けっぱなしの**まま**でかけてしまった。」

without changing the meanings.

Comment: Absolutely clear on the first part. But in the second part I was referring to something like follows.

Can **窓を開けっぱなしでかけてしまった** be rewritten as **窓を開けたままでかけてしまった**?

Comment: @RomeoSierra You can say 「窓を開けっぱなし**で**　でかけてしまった」「窓を開けたまま　でかけてしまった」「窓を開けたまま**で**　でかけてしまった」 but not 「窓を開けっぱなし　でかけてしまった」; 「開けっ放しで」「開けたまま」「開けたままで」 can function adverbially, but 「開けっ放し」 can't.

Comment: True that! Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! :)

Answer (score 2):

> （Ａ）水を出しっぱなしにしないでください
> （Ｂ）水を出したままにしないでください
>
> （Ａ）窓をあけっぱなしで出かけてしまった
> （Ｂ）窓をあけっぱなしのまま出かけてしまった

（Ａ）と（Ｂ）との違いは、誰が最初の行為をしたかと言う点です。
最初の行為とは、
「水が出ていない状態から水を出した人」です。
次の文章では、「窓が閉まった状態から開けた人」です。

（Ａ）は、最初の行為をした人と、その後の状態を放置した人が同一人物です。
（Ｂ）は、最初の行為をした人と、その後の状態を放置した人が同一人物かどうか不明です。

すなわち、「（Ａ）水を出しっぱなしにしないでください」の場合、水道の栓をひねって水を出した人に対して、用が済んだら、水道の栓をきちんと閉めるようにお願いしています。
一方、「（Ｂ）水を出したままにしないでください」の場合、勧告者が見たときには既に水が出ています。誰が水道の栓を開いたかは問題にしていません。ともかく、今水道の水を使っている人に向かって勧告者は水道の水を使い終わったら栓を閉めるようにお願いしています。

Answer (score 2):

Each of に and で has it's own set of meanings, and so naturally whether to use に or で after ～っぱなし depends on which particle is fitting given the idea or event you want to describe in words.

In the case of 水を出しっぱなし**に**する, which I provisionally translate to "*make the water left running*", the に marks a resulting state. The する (corresponding to *make* in the prov translation ) is a verb with the meaning "put [*something into some state*]". Matching this paradigm with the example phrase: *something* corresponds to *水/the water*; *some state* to *出しっぱなし/left running*; and *into* to に/(No corresponding word in the translation).

As for 窓をあけっぱなし**で**でかける (*leave with the window left open*), the particle で (corresponding to *with* in the translation) is used to mark a circumstance that accompanies an action or event. The circumstance in this example is *窓をあけっぱなし/the window left open*, and the action is *でかける/leave*.

Relevant sections at [東京外国語大学言語モジュール](http://www.coelang.tufs.ac.jp/mt/ja/gmod/contents/explanation/053.html)
:

(for the に)

> Ⅲ　「に」：６　変化の結果を表わします。
>   (39)氷が水になりました。
>   (40)山田さんは子どもを政治家にしました。

(for the で)

> Ⅷ　「で」：７　状態を表わす名詞について、状態を表わします。
>   (91)子どもがはだしで歩いています。
>   (92)子どもがはだかで走っています。